# Ext.util.Filter with multiple values

Tags: javascript, extjs, filter, extjs6

I am using following code to filter a store

```
var filter = new Ext.util.Filter({
        property: 'FIRST_NAME',
        value: 'ABC'
});

store.getFilters().add(filter);
```

This is working fine.

Now, I want to filter this with multiple values. 
I tried

```
    var filter = new Ext.util.Filter({
            property: 'FIRST_NAME',
            value: ('ABC' || 'XYZ')
    });

store.getFilters().add(filter);
```

but this returns only XYZ records. any other way to do this. I am using **sencha 6**.

Comment: If you're using 6.x, why did you tag the question with 4.x?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the `in` operator:

```
store.getFilters().add({
    property: 'FIRST_NAME',
    value: ['ABC', 'XYZ'],
    operator: 'in'
});
```